# Android Studio 3.o not giving android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I cant see android bar or see the app's design ! even when  try to reopen it or changing SDK path or any ordinary thing we do for things like this,And the Android Studio icon is green !

its just giving me the project with out the ANDROID
[HERE IS IT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD8Nc.png)

Comment: How did you open the project, try opening it again

Comment: I've created it one month ago and now when I tried to open it ... it did that and I cant see the Android or design

Comment: Re-open it.....

Comment: Didn't work ....

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the arrow next to the "Project" title (or just the title itself) and then switch to the "Android" view from the dropdown options.

[image: Dropdown options]

Comment: the problem is that the Android (which you are signing at) is not existed !

Comment: Can you help me ?